# Copy data from workbook to workbook with VBA using the date

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks that I am trying to achieve the following with:

1) Supervisor opens their daily report and clicks (1st shift/2nd shift/or 3rd shift). They then enter their total number of products produced (Product 1 value = P4, Product 2 value = P6, Product 3 value = P8, Product 4 value = P9)

2) They then submit the form using the button on the sheet and the following is achieved
a. Total Values listed above get transferred to another workbook that is unopened and logged accordingly. Product 1 = C2, Product 2 = C5, Product 3 = C8, and Product 4 = C11 which corresponds to the appropriate Date inside the log.

**2nd Part of Wkbk**

Then my next Operator comes in and picks (1st shift/2nd shift/or 3rd shift). They enter their total number of products produced (Product 1 value = P4, Product 2 value = P6, Product 3 value = P8, Product 4 value = P9)

They then submit the form using the button on the sheet and the following is achieved
a. Total Values listed above get transferred to another workbook that is unopened and logged accordingly. Product 1 = C3, Product 2 = C6, Product 3 = C9, and Product 4 = C13 which corresponds to the appropriate Date inside the log.

Etc for all 3 shifts....

Then the next day they come in and do it all over again and the submitted totals shift to the appropriate column for the date the parts were ran.

I also forgot to mention that when they submit the form it automatically saves it in a specified location with the Date and Shift in the name as well as generates an email to a pre-determined list of recipients who need to review this data on a daily basis.

I am not sure how to get the date feature to work so that the data goes into the right location in the log book. I am also not sure how to get the cells to index to the appropriate location based off the date. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Code so far:

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim WkBk As Workbook
Dim SrcWkBk As Workbook
Dim Shift As Integer
Dim myDate As Date

Set SrcWkBk = ThisWorkbook
Set WkBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\FILE LOCATION.xlsm")
dDate = SrcWkBk.Sheets("Hourly Counts").Range("E2")
'Set rCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:V1").Find(What:=dDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

Shift = Range("B2").Value

With WkBk
Dim rCell As Range
Set rCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:V1").Find(What:=dDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

'Copy Total Number of Parts per Line
If Shift = 1 Then

 SrcWkBk.Sheets("Hourly Counts").Range("P4").Copy
   WkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   SrcWkBk.Sheets("Hourly Counts").Range("P6").Copy
   WkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ElseIf Shift = 2 Then
SrcWkBk.Sheets("Hourly Counts").Range("P4").Copy
   WkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   SrcWkBk.Sheets("Hourly Counts").Range("P6").Copy
   WkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ElseIf Shift = 3 Then
SrcWkBk.Sheets("Hourly Counts").Range("P4").Copy
   WkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   SrcWkBk.Sheets("Hourly Counts").Range("P6").Copy
   WkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

End With


'wkbook the code resides in....
WkBk.SaveAs ("C:\FILE LOCATION" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsm")
Clear Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This is the main file (pic 1) that assembly will enter their data into before submitting it to be logged into the log file (pic 2).

[image: Log File]

[image: Assembly Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Well here's a cleaner version of what you have going because I intend to come back to this and adjust it later.

```
Sub TransferData()
    
    Dim wsS As Worksheet
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hourly Counts")
    
    Dim wsD As Workbook
    Set wsD = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\FILE LOCATION.xlsm").Sheets(1)

    'Dim dDate As Date
    'dDate = wsS.Range("E2").value
    '
    'Dim rCell As Range
    'Set rCell = wsD.Range("C1:V1").Find(What:=dDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    Select Case wsS.Range("B2").Value2
        Case 1
            wsD.Range("C2").Value2 = wsS.Range("P4").Value2
            wsD.Range("C5").Value2 = wsS.Range("P6").Value2
        Case 2
            wsD.Range("C3").Value2 = wsS.Range("P4").Value2
            wsD.Range("C6").Value2 = wsS.Range("P6").Value2
        Case 3
            wsD.Range("C4").Value2 = wsS.Range("P4").Value2
            wsD.Range("C7").Value2 = wsS.Range("P6").Value2
    End Select
    
    wbD.SaveAs ("C:\FILE LOCATION" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsm")
    
End Sub
```

**However**, I would seriously recommend that you create a small mockup version of your sheets so that I or others can visualize what it is you really want to accomplish. Doing so would help me/us answer questions like this

> > not sure how to get the date feature to work so that the data goes into the right location in the log book
>
> it automatically saves it in a specified location with the Date

Where is this "specified location" ?

One way that you could work this project is to search based on the date result you get from the `Now()` function and check if today's `DateDiff()` minus one day matches up.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response to my question. I have tried running your code and I get the following error "Run time error-438" when the code gets to the Case portion. I will try and add some images of what the files are that I am working with to help clarify. Again I appreciate your assistance on this.